# Trying to get property 'total_rooms' of non-object"

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

am getting this weird bug which I have tried to debug I can find the solution to it. so here I have a modal whereby a user registers their account at. in the modal there is rental houses dropdown where the user only selects their house then proceeds to select their room, then they proceed to fill in all the other inputs, then registers their account upon clicking a button.
here is the bug am getting, the modal works very well on all other pages except on the house details page. it toggles perfectly and shows all the inputs and the first rental houses dropdown where a user first selects their rental houses. but the 2nd dropdown that shows all the rooms doesn't show and instead I see [image: this] error in the network tab. here is the method in the controller where the error is coming from.

```
public function singlehsedetails ($rental_slug,$id){ 
$rentalhouse=Rental_house::with
('housetags','rentalalternateimages','houselocation','hsesusers')
->find($id);
$occupiedroomscount=Room_name::where('rentalhouse_id',$id)->where('is_occupied',1)->count();
        //this line below
$availablerooms=$rentalhouse->total_rooms-$occupiedroomscount;   
$relatedhouses=Rental_house::where(['rental_status'=>1,'is_extraimages'=>1,'is_rentable'=>1])->where('id','!=',$id)->take(3)->get();
$isfeaturedhouses=Rental_house::where(['rental_status'=>1,'is_extraimages'=>1,'is_featured'=>'yes'])->get();
$activereviews=Houseratingreview::where(['rating_isactive'=>1,'hse_id'=>$id])->get();
        
return view('Front.Rentalslisting.rentalhsedetails',compact('allowreview','userrating','availablerooms','rentalhouse','relatedhouses','isfeaturedhouses'));
}
```

the function is the one that shows details of a house.
my modal is on the master's page. all the other inputs work very well. here is what the rental house dropdown looks like.

```
<div class="row section-groups">
                          <div class="form-group inputdetails col-sm-6" style="color: black; font-size:18px;">
                              <label>House Name<span class="text-danger inputrequired">*</span></label><br>
                              <select name="rentalhousename" id="rentalhsenme" class="rentalhsename form-control text-white bg-dark" style="width:100%;" required>
                                <option>Select Your Rental House </option>
                                   <?php 
                                      $activehousenames=Rental_house::select('rental_name','id')->where(['rental_status'=>1,'is_vacancy'=>1,'is_rentable'=>1])->get();
                                   ?>
                                   @foreach($activehousenames as $housename)
                                      <option value="{{ $housename->id }}">
                                         {{ $housename->rental_name }}</option>
                                   @endforeach
                              </select>
                          </div>
  
                          <div class="form-group inputdetails col-sm-6">
                             <label>Room Name/Number<span class="text-danger inputrequired">*</span></label>
                             <br>
                             <select name="getroomnamenumber" class="roomnamenumber form-control text-white bg-dark" required style="width: 100%;">
                                <option value=" " disabled="true" selected="true">Select Your Room Name/Number</option>
                             </select>
                          </div>
                      </div>
```

here is my ajax code

// show rooms for a house on dropdown

```
      $(document).on('change','#rentalhsenme',function(){
        var hsetitle_id=$( "#rentalhsenme" ).val();
        $.ajax({
           type:'get',
           url:'getroomsforahouse',
           data:{
              'id':hsetitle_id
           },
           success:function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                 $('.roomnamenumber').html('<option disabled selected value=" ">Select Your Room Name/Number</option>');
                 
                 console.log("the data is ",data);
                 data.forEach((room)=>{
                    console.log(room);
                    $('.roomnamenumber').append('<option value="'+room.id+'">'+room.room_name+'</option>');
                 });
                 
           },error:function(){
           }
        });
     });
```

I have imported the rental house details at the top of the master's page.
am using jquery to auto-populate the options for the rooms and works very well on other pages. am trying to think where the error is coming from because the modal works very well on other pages but when it comes here to the rental house details page the dropdown doesn't work.

the page loads very well and shows the data.only that the dropdown doesnt respond

Comment: Your error is pretty clear. It is saying that on this line: `$rentalhouse->total_rooms`, you're trying to access `->total_rooms` from `$rentalhouse`, but `$rentalhouse` is not an Object, so you can't use `->total_rooms`. Did you do any kind of debugging? `\Log::info($rentalhouse)`, or `dd($rentalhouse)`, etc. Or use `findOrFail()` instead of `find()`, etc.

Comment: @TimLewis yes i tried dd($rentalhouse) and i get the number of total rooms

Comment: The error looks like it's coming from an ajax request(?) so can you share the code that sends that?

Comment: @apokryfos the dropdown works very well in other pages except in this specific page..let me add the ajax code  to the question.am tring to think of it as if the model in Rental_house model and the Rental_house model in the modal are conflicting?

Comment: If the AJAX request is meant to call the controller method you shared then you should be passing the ID in the URL instead of the data e.g. `url:'getroomsforahouse/'+hsetitle_id,`

Comment: I think you're missing a couple URL parameters. You're calling `url:'getroomsforahouse'`, but your method is `public function singlehsedetails ($rental_slug,$id)`; how are `$rental_slug` and `$id` being populated? I would expect your URL to be something like `url:'getroomsforahouse/example-slug/1'` (or similar)

Comment: @TimLewis this is the route that calls the method   
 ```Route::get('rentalhse/{rental_slug}/{id}', [Rentalslisting_controller::class,'singlehsedetails'])->name('singlehse.details');``` while this other one is the one that is being callled in the ajax code     ```Route::get('/getroomsforahouse', [Home_controller::class,'getroomsforahouse'])->name('getrooms.house');```

Comment: Then you need to sort out which method is being called by what, if the parameters are being populated properly, etc etc. Also, please fix your Class, Variable and Method names. Classes should be `HomeController`, `RentalListingController`, etc. Methods should be `singleHouseDetails()`, `getRoomsForHouse()`, etc. Your code is not following naming conventions at all, which makes it pretty hard to follow/figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TimLewis i will fix that..but what might the error be coming from considering in the modal am calling another method

Comment: I don't know; you'll need [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73623450/edit) and clarify what is happening. I'm having trouble following your code (I'm sorry, and I don't mean to be rude when I say this, but it is a bit of a cryptic mess), so I'm not sure what code is calling what, what code is causing that error, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was coming from my ajax request.i had wrongly wrote the url.i changed to this and it all worked very well

```
$(document).on('change','#rentalhsenme',function(){
    var hsetitle_id=$( "#rentalhsenme" ).val();
   var getroomsurl = '{{ route("getrooms.house") }}';
    $.ajax({
       type:'get',
       url:getroomsurl,
       data:{
          'id':hsetitle_id
       },
       success:function(data){
             console.log(data);
             $('.roomnamenumber').html('<option disabled selected value=" ">Select Your Room Name/Number</option>');
             
             console.log("the data is ",data);
             data.forEach((room)=>{
                console.log(room);
                $('.roomnamenumber').append('<option value="'+room.id+'">'+room.room_name+'</option>');
             });
             
       },error:function(){
       }
    });
 });
```